# Switching from 3D to 2D in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, opengl-4

I'm making a weather simulation in Opengl 4.0 and am trying to create the sky by creating a fullscreen quad in the background. I'm trying to do that by having the vertex shader generate four vertexes and then drawing a triangle strip. Everything compiles just fine and I can see all the other objects I've made before, but the sky is nowhere to be seen. What am I doing wrong?

**main.cpp**

```
GLint stage = glGetUniformLocation(myShader.Program, "stage");
//...
glBindVertexArray(FS); //has four coordinates (-1,-1,1) to (1,1,1) in buffer object
glUniform1i(stage, 1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

**vertex shader**

```
uniform int stage;
void main()
{
    if (stage==1)
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }    
}
```

**fragment shader**

```
uniform int stage;
void main()
{
    if (stage==1)
    { //placeholder gray colour so I can see the sky
        color = vec4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I should also mention that I'm a beginner in OpenGL and that it really **has to** be in OpenGL 4.0 or later.

**EDIT:**
I've figured out where's the problem, but still don't know how to fix it. The square exists, but only displays if I multiply it with the view and projection matrix (but then it doesn't stay glued to the screen and just rotates along with the rest of the scene, which I do not want). Essentially, I somehow need to switch back to 2D or to screen space or however it's called, draw the square, and switch back to 3D so that all the other objects work fine. How?

Comment: Try setting `z` coords in your vertex array to `0`. That `1` is exactly on the far clipping plane, and might be the issue. Also, if you have face culling enabled, make sure your plane points are in counter-clockwise order. (might also want to disable depth buffer writes for this, and draw it *first*!).

Comment: If your shader is doing two completely different things like that based on a uniform that gets switched once, then what you really have are two shaders. Ubershaders are nice and all, but there's no reason to go to such extremes for completely different kinds of rendering operations.

Comment: @NicolBolas I already have an idea how to remove that 'if' completely, but the condition makes it easy to track until I manage to get it to work.

Comment: @TimČas It worked! I set the z plane to 0.9999f and now the square is visible and glued to the screen, and the objects only clip out if I zoom really far away – it would be better if they never did that (any further advice?), but now it should okay for all practical purposes.

This is my first time on SO; how do I give you points?

Comment: @Gweddry: Can you draw the sky *before* the rest of the scene? If you can, you can simply disable depth writes (& possibly tests if you haven't cleared the depth buffer yet), and then draw the sky at depth 0, as in `(+/- 1, +/- 1, 0)`. And you can give points by clicking on the small triangle that appears on the left of the comment if you hover over it (not sure if there's a min. reputation limit for that, though) --- but don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with putting a 1 as the z coord – putting 0.999f instead solved the issue.

Comment: You could have probably also set your depth test to `gl.LEQUAL` or turned off depth testing. Since the default is `gl.LESS` and usually you clear depth to 1.0 then setting Z at 1.0 means your quad was not less and so failed the test.  Also, you can create a simple skybox by [drawing a quad and using a cubemap](http://twgljs.org/examples/no-box-skybox.html).